# Size of AdMob native ads

Tags: ios, iphone, admob

What is the size of AdMob native ads for large ads?

My UIView size is 300 * 300 and I used native large ads.

It gives an error like:

> Error: No ad to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a "**Large**" AdMob native ads you can use widths between 280 and 1200 dp, and heights from 250 to 1200 dp. That means 300 by 300 is valid for the Large template size.

For more information, you can look  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/native-express

> Error: No ad to show.

The ad server will return this message mainly because there are no ads for your ad unit id. Check whether your ad unit id is proper or not.

Try with the ad unit ID for testing: **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511**

AdMob available this ad unit ID for use.

Comment: I used unit id but it display error : "No ad to show."

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging to test your ads you need to use your test device id.

for debugging use:

```
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("BB6B8630BC49F8850B714C06E65DB592").build());
```

BB6B8630BC49F8850B714C06E65DB592 is your test device id.

You can get your test device id from your logs.
When your device is ready for debugging select verbose and type "Ads" on tag.

you would get something like this:

```
06-09 23:05:36.985 2347-2347/<package> I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("9FEE2036743C6A58AF69BA3A505316A9") to get test ads on this device.
```